# c++ shipping assignment terminates automatically

Tags: c++

Hello my program terminates automatically after calculating shipping charges. Can you tell me what I did wrong? Also, is my shipping charges look accurate? Thank you so much!

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    const int distanceunit = 500;
    double rate = 0, shippingcost=0;
    int weight=0, distance=0, Distanceunit2=0;

    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;

    cout << "How much does the package weigh in pounds?";
    cin >> weight;

    //Shipping rate`---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //if (weight <= 0) {
    //  cout << "The weight should be greater than 0" << endl;
    //}//need to include else
    //if (weight >20) {
    //  cout << "The weight should be 20" << endl;
    //}
    //else {
    //  cout << "How far will the package be going?"<<endl;
    //  cin >> distance;
    //}

    if (weight <= 0 || weight >20) {
        cout << "We only accept packages between 1 to 20 kg."<<endl;
        cout << "Enter new weight"<<endl;
        cin >> weight;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Enter the distance to be shipped(in miles):";
        cin >> distance;
    }


    if (distance < 10 || distance>3000) {
        cout << "The distance you entered is not in the mn and max range" << endl;
        cout << "Enter new distance" << endl;
        cin >> distance;
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Distanceunit2 = distance / distanceunit;
        if (weight <= 2) {
            rate = 1.10;
        }
        else if (weight > 2 && weight <= 6) {
            rate = 2.20;
        }
        else if (weight > 6 && weight <= 10) {
            rate = 3.70;
        }
        else {
            rate = 4.80;
        }

    if (distance%distanceunit != 0) {
        shippingcost = Distanceunit2 * rate;
    }
    else {
        shippingcost = rate;
    }



        cout << "The cost to ship a package that weighs " << weight
            << " kilograms for a distance of " << distance
            << " miles is $" << shippingcost << endl << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Another problem is that it will validate my weight one time but on the second try, it goes automatically to the else block. So if i were to enter 0 for my weight, it says it cant be 0. I try again for 21 and it goes automatically to ask my distance instead of validating it again. It does the same thing for my distance.

Comment: Do you mean the program terminates unusually, or does it terminates normally because it reached the end of `main`?

Comment: I suggest you create functions to simplify.  For example, a user prompt and fetch of the response might be useful. Consider "int promptForInt (std::string promptTxt)".  This will simplify the response validation and simplify within a loop when your user must re-enter.

Comment: Prompted for weight in pounds, but the 'cost to ship' is kilograms and miles?  Probably unintended unit change.  more than one place.  Review all units.

Comment: I don't understand the rate determination.  Maybe need more comments?

Comment: Your problem description  "my program terminates automatically after calculating shipping charges" is inadequate, and does not allow us to help you much.  Can you explain? perhaps  See [MCVE] ... and if you a) provide test inputs, and b) expected results, we can certainly help more.  good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible (but minimally tested) prompting code.

Caution: the code does not detect or recover from the invalid user input, i.e. a letter instead of a digit.

```
   int promptForInt(std::string promptTxt, 
                    std::string label, 
                    std::string units)
      {
         int t = 0;
         std::cout << promptTxt;  
         cin >> t;
         cout << "\n  " << label << "  " << t 
              << "  " << units << std::endl;
         return t;
      }
```

And a possible (minimally tested) prompt / response usage.

Caution: this is an infinite loop, which you probably want to avoid.

```
weight = promptForInt("\n  How much does the package weigh in pounds?",
                      "weight:", "pounds");

// range check prompt loop
while ((weight <= 0) || (weight >20))
{
   cout << "\n  We only accept packages between 1 to 20 kg."<<endl;
   weight = promptForInt(
       "\n  How much does the package weigh in pounds?", 
       "weight:", "pounds");
}
```

You should look for other prompting examples, because my work was in embedded systems, (so this is not my usual effort). My team was required to use more 'sophisticated' approaches (research TL1, snmp, and maybe 'telnet' curses based ui).